unable to export deploymentgroup via pmrep. is it supported?
object_type Deploymentgroup does not work for me using pmrep
pmrep objectexport -n dg_map1 -o Deploymentgroup -f test -u c:\temp\zzz.xml
Unknown or unsupported object type Deploymentgroup.
I think  i read somewhere that it is supported. If it is supported in client probably it is supported in cmd too

can you pls check if deployment group exists ? and you have access to that ? you havent mentioned any version but assuming 10.x, this seems to be a valid command. also check if pmrep connect works or not.

hi - I'm connected . my version is 10.4.1. The deployment group exists. this is the error  - Unknown or unsupported object type Deploymentgroup.
